# How to implement shaderToy's buffer in pixiJs

Tags: three.js, fragment-shader, pixi.js

I can declare multiple buffers as temporary textures in threejs and compute each other to get the final result.

The implementation code for threeJs is as follows

```
this.bufferA = new BufferShader(BUFFER_A_FRAG, {
          iFrame: {
            value: 0
          },
          iResolution: {
            value: resolution
          },
          iMouse: {
            value: this.mousePosition
          },
          iChannel0: {
            value: null
          },
          iChannel1: {
            value: null
          }
        });

        this.bufferB = new BufferShader(BUFFER_B_FRAG, {
          iFrame: {
            value: 0
          },
          iResolution: {
            value: resolution
          },
          iMouse: {
            value: this.mousePosition
          },
          iChannel0: {
            value: null
          }
        });

        this.bufferImage = new BufferShader(BUFFER_FINAL_FRAG, {
          iResolution: {
            value: resolution
          },
          iMouse: {
            value: this.mousePosition
          },
          iChannel0: {
            value: channel0
          },
          iChannel1: {
            value: null
          }
        });

      }
```

By enclosing targetA. ReadBuffer. Texture, I can achieve the desired effect

```
 animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {

          this.bufferA.uniforms['iFrame'].value = this.counter++;

          this.bufferA.uniforms['iChannel0'].value = this.targetA.readBuffer.texture;
          this.bufferA.uniforms['iChannel1'].value = this.targetB.readBuffer.texture;
          this.targetA.render(this.bufferA.scene, this.orthoCamera);

          this.bufferB.uniforms['iChannel0'].value = this.targetB.readBuffer.texture;
          this.targetB.render(this.bufferB.scene, this.orthoCamera);

          this.bufferImage.uniforms['iChannel1'].value = this.targetA.readBuffer.texture;
          this.targetC.render(this.bufferImage.scene, this.orthoCamera, true);

          this.animate();

        });
```

But I can't find the buffer api in pixijs.

Does pixiJs support this api for storing the fs shader result as a texture and continuing to color it